# Entity Core: Select Anonymous Type and Count Error : No value provided for required parameter _outer

Tags: parameters, entity-framework-core, outer-join, anonymous

I have some problems with Entity Framework Core 1.1 when I try to select and count into Anonymous Type

> Error: InvalidOperationException: No value provided for required
> parameter '_outer_ProductCategoryID'.

Code:

```
 rets = context.ProductCategories.Select
                          (
                              y => new ProductCategory
                              {
                                  Title = y.Title,
                                  ProductCategoryID = y.ProductCategoryID,
                                  ProductCount = y.ProductCategoryFiles.Count()

                              }
                          ).ToList();
```

Comment: Same issue here, seems like maybe ef core limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Will be fixed in 1.1.2 EF release. More here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7714

Workaround is to first do count in plain anonymous dynamic object and then do projection into your DTO:

```
context.ProductCategories.Select(c => new { Count = c.ProductCategoryFiles.Count() }).ToList().Select(r => new ProductCategoryDTO { Count = r.Count,... });
```